# Why is this shader using multiple render targets not working?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I have a webgl shader that uses multiple render targets. This one only renders to one texture for now. However, I plan that this shader shall render more. However, as soon as I add layout qualifiers, and #version 300 es, my shader stops working, because I get a message saying it is an invalid program.

```
  #version 300 es

  uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;

  attribute vec3 vertex;
  attribute vec2 uv;

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(vertex, 1);
    vUv = uv;
  }
```

Fragment shader

```
  #version 300 es

  precision mediump float;

  layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

  uniform sampler2D textureId;

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    color = texture2D(textureId, vUv);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a WebGL version 1 (OpenGL ES 2.0) and that's why it does not accept OpenGL ES 3.x features.

Review the code where you request the context for WebGL

```
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");   // 2!
```

If you are requesting WebGL2, check that there are no whitespaces before `#version 300 es`.

You can find additional guidance [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html).